# How to search through a JSON?

Tags: php, json, search

I'm trying to search through this Json array using PHP:

```
{"count":"2","items":{"milestone":[{"id":"3107","username":"TomSmith1","userid":"1620602","date":"2012-01-12 16:49:26","projectid":"804","projectname":"TEST PROJECT","reason":"Partial payment for project","amount":"25","currency":"1"},{"id":"3111","username":"HarryCole","userid":"1620603","date":"2012-01-13 16:42:39","projectid":"804","projectname":"TEST PROJECT 2","reason":"Partial payment for project","amount":"10","currency":"1"}]}}
```

I want to search through this to find the "id", which has the project name "TEST PROJECT 2" and the username "HarryCole". I've attempted this using a `foreach` loop but haven't succeeded. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. It was basically what Michael answered but I didn't realise I had to decode the Json. Probably why I was having no joy. :P I'll try it out now with decoding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need https://www.php.net/json_decode and also a foreach loop like

```
foreach($json_decoded as $key=>$value) {
     // Check for id / values
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain what $key=>$value is? Would it be something like $key=>milestone ? Thanks again.

Comment: $key would be the array indice, and $value is the value.  Like $array[1] = "blah"; $key would be 1 and $value = "blah"

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `json_decode($json, true)` on the string to transform it from JSON to PHP notation (an associative array).

Comment: +1. If you want to use foreach or any array operations, you need to json_decode. Don't forget true on the second argument or you'll get an object instead of an array.